What does `sudo chmod -R a=,a+rX,u+w,g+w /data` do?
What does the following command do?
sudo chmod -R a=,a+rX,u+w,g+w /data
I understand that it changes permissions, but what exactly and how?

It applies the following permission changes to all files and directories under /data (including /data):

a= clears all permissions
a+rX grants read permissions to everyone, and execute permissions to everyone on all directories (see What is a capital X in posix / chmod?)
u+w grants write permissions to each file’s owner
g+w grants write permissions to each file’s group

-R applies the permission changes recursively. Permission changes separated by commas are applied sequentially (so +rX doesn’t make any file executable — since it comes after a=, no file is executable).
The result is that all of /data is readable by everyone and writable by the relevant owner and group.

If there are subdirectories, do they become inaccessible now, as x would have been removed from them?

@muru no, X applies to directories and (separately) files with any execute permission set.
